# how to submit a html form by webview in react-native

Tags: html, react-native, webview

I got a web page by fetch in react-native. The web page is like :

```
<html><body onload="document.forms[0].submit();"><form action='XXX' method="post"><input type="hidden" name="keywords" value='hello' /></form></html>
```

.
 Then how can I post this web page in react-native?

Comment: Add `<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>` to your code.

Comment: I can't modify the web page ,because it is also used in other place.

Answer (score 4):

It is resolved by WebView. Like this:

```
<WebView source={{html:'<html><body onload="document.forms[0].submit();"><form action='XXX' method="post"><input type="hidden" name="keywords" value='hello' /></form></html>
'}}></WebView>.
```